# Select rows where json column array contains specific value with mySQL

Tags: mysql, json, database

I am creating a filter system for a website, however, I am unable to search MySQL database columns with JSON data.

An example of the column data is exactly like the following example:

***["Self", "Homework", "Discussion"]***

The entire database table looks like this:

```
id |  name   |   type   |   subject   |   work 
__________________________________________________________________________
1  | 'name1' | 'type1'  | ["a", "b"]  | ["Self", "Homework", "Discussion"]
2  | 'name2' | 'type2'  | ["b"]       | ["Self", "Discussion"]
1  | 'name3' | 'type3'  | ["a", "b"]  | ["Self", "Homework"]
```

I want to select all rows that contain `homework` in the `work` array.

Note: I need the solution to work for `subject` as well since they have the same array structure.

I tried this MySQL commands but they do not seem to work.

```
SELECT * FROM materialData WHERE JSON_SEARCH(materialWork, 'all', 'Self')
```

```
SELECT * FROM materialData WHERE JSON_EXTRACT(materialWork, '$') = 'Self'
```

Both of these return:

`MySQL returned an empty result set`

Is there any way I can select rows based on values in a columns array?

I read some MySQL documentation from mysql.com but I have not taken a full course. I only know MySQL basics from PHP courses. Therefore, please don't judge any simple or dumb mistake.

EDIT:

1. Someone suggests I normalize the database and create a new table.

Is there no other way? Creating a new table will be very problematic, especially in the future when I expand my project.

Essentially a user will choose one or more subjects from 42 options provided (This is what I provide currently, the number of subjects will expand in the future). Therefore, from what I understand I have to make a table with 42 columns?

Again I apologize if this a stupid question!

However, creating a new table for `work` is not a problem.

Comment: Do not save JSON in column if you want to search for the contents. Normalize your database and use a second table for the work

Comment: So it is not possible to search for JSON content? Because for one of the columns it would require more than 20 columns. Or should I go ahead with the 20+ columns?

Comment: No you should not add 20 columns. You should add a table name it work. This table has two columns. Homework-I’d and Name. For each entry in the Json you will then add a row to this table

Comment: That would be a solution. I will make that Plan B, however, because I would have to rewrite more then a couple of hundred lines of code. Hopefully, I can find a simple solution

Comment: That’s a good point thinking if your source code design is a good one. If you had followed the mvc pattern you could change this very easy

Comment: Yes, that was a horrible mistake.

Comment: Check [JSON_CONTAINS](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-search-functions.html#function_json-contains) and [value MEMBER OF(json_array)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-search-functions.html#operator_member-of).